# Integrating wso2 BAM with external cassandra

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to integrate external cassandra to BAM. I have changed cassandra-component.xml.

1) I want to know how keyspace are created on external cassandra because when I am running BAM,
   I am getting the error `Unknown keyspace EVENT_KS`.

2) I am having the following error in my wso2 logs

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-02-11 15:28:30,905]  WARN {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient} -  Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same. {org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient}

TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-02-11 15:37:04,393] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Job Submission failed with exception 'java.lang.RuntimeException(org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException)'
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getRangeMap(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:297)

    at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:105)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardColumnInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCassandraStandardColumnInputFormat.java:291)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.HiveCassandraStandardColumnInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCassandraStandardColumnInputFormat.java:216)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:302)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:292)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:933)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:925)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:839)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:792)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1123)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:792)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:766)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:460)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:733)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

Answer (score 0):

EVENT_KS is created only after the very first event is published to BAM as I remember. If you try to access it before getting created errors may arise.

Answer (score 0):

In BAM 2.4.0, EVENT_KS is getting created when you run the BAM for the first time. (But in previous versions EVENT_KS will be created when the very first event is published to BAM). Please make sure your cassandra-component.xml looks similar to something like below. Also tell us about the cassandra version you are using.

```
<Cassandra><Cluster>
    <Name>Test Cluster</Name>
    <DefaultPort>9160</DefaultPort>
    <Nodes>localhost:9160</Nodes>
    <AutoDiscovery disable="false" delay="1000"/>
</Cluster></Cassandra>
```

Comment: cassandra version is 2.0.5

Answer (score 0):

First You need to check the following:

1. Have you pointed the cassandra-component.xml correctly to the external cassandra. With this your published data will be stored in the intended external cassandra database.
2. Have you installed a toolbox with intended stream definition inside? Or Else have you triggered to publish the data to BAM? In both cases the EVENT_KS will be created with the column family with the name of stream.
3. Have you modified the $BAM_HOME/repository/conf/datasource/master-datasource.xml to point to external cassandra databse? You need to validate the cassandra database configuration provided in WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE datasource. For the default toolboxes, this is the default cassandra datasource being used and by default it points to localhost. If you are using this in your hive script you need to change this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After putting many efforts i figure that after changing data directory of cassendra.yaml of external cassandra to repository/database/cassandra/data everything works fine with external cassandra.Not to mention with version 1.1.3. I want to know is there any other work around for this external cassandra configuration.

Comment: To make sure everything works fine, publish some data by running one of the samples[1] and check whether hive queries are also executing properly. If hive queries executing without a problem and summarized results are displayed in dashboards then you are good to go.
[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Analysing+HTTPD+Logs